# How to make vector arrow show up in the PDF text layer correctly?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, unicode-math, accents, viewers

Feeding the input

```
%%% No PDF compression so that you can read PDF as plaintext as possible:
\edef\pdfcompresslevel{\pdfvariable compresslevel}
\edef\pdfobjcompresslevel{\pdfvariable objcompresslevel}
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\vec{C}\)
\end{document}
```

to `lualatex` (or to `xelatex` without the pdf compression stuff) produces an arrow over math italic capital  in print.

When selected in the editor `evince`, we see a plain
[image: selected ouput], without the arrow. Copying and pasting it produces simply .

When selected in the editor `okular`, we get C ⃗ at best (namely, if we select the two symbols in text or area mode with a mouse explicitly). Note that the arrow is not above C but right above C.

Any idea on how to get copyable ⃗ (U+1D436 combined with U+20D7) in the text layer for `evince` or `okular`?

Apparently, `Vivaldi` gives the representation we want, but is it due to the PDF having no blank after  or due to Vivaldi swallowing the blank after ?

Comment: Could it be a viewer issue? It works for me on `okular`.

Comment: @campa Wow. That' strange: `okular` gives us C ⃗ (unfortunately, not ⃗, and not even C⃗) in the area selection mode. When the selection mode is text, we get just C. Any idea what happens there?

Comment: I opened the PDF with my browser (vivaldi) and it works. I think it depends where you copy it to.

Comment: @Namal Checked with Vivaldi and got ⃗. So, the characters are apparently there, and I'm unsure about the spaces. I now think it depends where you copy *from*. Do you think that Vivaldi swallowed the space present in the PDF or that okular added space absent in the PDF? When I look into the PDF, I see `<20D7>` and lots of other stuff I cannot understand.

Comment: I don't think so, just installed and tried it out with okular and I get the result as with vivaldi. The copy part is a bit tricky though, select all (ctrl+A) does not select the arrow. While in Vivaldi it does.

Comment: @Namal For me it's different than for you then.  In `okular`, I went for the area selection (Ctrl+3), used the mouse to choose a large area surrounding the symbols, chose “Copy to Clipboard” from the appeared context menu, and then pasted here: C ⃗. As you see, the arrow is not above C but right above C, and the C is not math italic but upright.

Comment: Try selecting with ctrl+4 instead.

Comment: @Namal In okular, I press Ctrl+4 (Text Selection), select the character and the arrow with a mouse (yes, it turned out to be tricky, as you rightfully said, because Ctrl+A doesn't select the arrow), right-click for the context menu, choose “Copy Text”, and paste here: C ⃗ . As you see, the arrow is right above instead of above, and C is upright text, not italic math.

Comment: C ⃗ is what I get when I copy from okular to here. Do you by any chance copy out of a Virtual machine to a windows host? When I do that, I get the result you have.

Comment: @Namal No, I do it under native Linux environment (Gnome, Firefox). If you paste in, say, emacs or gedit, you also see that the arrow is to the right of C. In emacs, you even see the blank in between.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote my comment and switched back and forth between my ubuntu vm and the windows host I noticed that in Vivaldi on ubuntu I have a different result than on Vivaldi on Windows. Here are the results:

vivaldi-ubuntu:

[image: vivaldi-ubuntu]

vivaldi-windows:

[image: vivaldi-windows]

firefox-windows:

[image]

edge-windows:

[image]

As you can see it is a viewer issue of chromium browsers on windows.
Edit:...aaand macOS

Safari:
[image]

vivaldi-macOS:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think we wish less to test what the comments look like in various browsers on various platforms but rather interpret what is in there in the PDF.